# I am facing problem while fetching data from database using prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

My DB Name is 'cart'.
Table Name is 'products'.
row are 'id', 'name', 'image', 'price'.

I am getting this error.

***Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in E:\xammp\htdocs\cart\cart.php on line 9***

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4GYH.png)

Here is the Code

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cart');
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products`";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $query);

if($stmt){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'issi', $id, $name, $image, $price);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $name, $image, $price);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
        echo "<pre>";
        echo $id;
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: No of binding parameters does not match.

Comment: I know, but i am not able to understand this.can you please point out ?? binding parameter are 4. first one is int, second and third one is string and last one is also int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please dont't use "Select *", always select your columns instead.

uncomment the following line:

```
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'issi', $id, $name, $image, $price);
```

You don't need this for binding params in your result.

If you would have any params in your SELECT Statement that you want to bind, you can use mysqli_stmt_bind_param(....), but here it's not possible so you get this error.

More information here: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Answer (score 0):

as i see, you are not using any bound parameters in your query, like "SELECT * FROM product WHERE price = ? AND id = ?"

http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: I don't want to select any specific data. I want to SELECT All Data from the table.

Comment: i think, the you dont need to bind parameters, but only fetch the result from query "SELECT * from table_name"

Comment: So, Should i remove this link

" mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'issi', $id, $name, $image, $price);"